# Large mysql query with group by

Tags: mysql

I have a pricing history table with half a billion records. It is formatted like this:

`Id, sku, vendor, price, datetime`

What I want to do is get average price of all products by vendor for a certain date range. Most products are updated once every 3 days, but it varies.

So, this is the query I want to run:

```
SELECT 
    avg(price) 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    vendor='acme' 
    AND datetime > '12-15-2014' 
    AND datetime < '12-18-2014' 
GROUP BY sku
```

This 3 day range is broad enough that i will for sure get at least one price sample, but some skus may have been sampled more than once, hence group by to try and get only one instance of each sku.

The problem is, this query runs and runs and doesn't seem to finish (more than 15 minutes). There are around 500k unique skus.

Any ideas?

edit: corrected asin to sku

Comment: maybe try to add an index. did you look at the execution plan?

Comment: 1. Show the exact `SHOW CREATE TABLE` 2. Show `EXPLAIN` 3. How many rows satisfy the `WHERE vendor='acme' AND datetime > '12-15-2014' AND datetime < '12-18-2014' ` condition?

Comment: Alternative use; `datetime BETWEEN '12-15-2014' AND '12-18-2014'`

Comment: @slime the original one will not match `12-15-2014 00:00:00` while your one will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query to be optimized by mysql you need to create a composite index

```
(vendor, datetime, asin)
```

**IN THIS PARTICULAR ORDER** (it mattters)

It also worth trying creating another one

```
(vendor, datetime, asin, price)
```

since it *may* perform better (since it's a so called "covering index").

The indexes with other order, like `(datetime, vendor)` (which is suggested in another answer) are useless since the `datetime` is used in a range comparison.

Few notes:

- The index will be helpful if only the `vendor='acme' AND datetime > '12-15-2014' AND datetime < '12-18-2014'` filter condition covers a small part of the whole table (say less than 10%)
- Mysql does not support `dd-mm-yyyy` literals (at least it's not documented, see references) so I assume it must be `yyyy-mm-dd` instead
- Your comparison does not cover the first second of the December 15th, 2014. So you probably wanted `datetime >= '2014-12-15'` instead.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an index to support your query. Suggest you create an index on vendor and datetime like so:

```
CREATE INDEX pricing_history_date_vendor ON pricing_history (datetime, vendor);
```

Also, I assume you wanted to group by `sku` rather than undefined column `asin`.

Not to mention your non-standard SQL date format `MM-dd-yyyy` as pointed out by others in comments (should be `yyyy-MM-dd`).

Comment: There is a range comparison over `datetime`, so for the given query `vendor` part of your index will never be used

Comment: @zerkms According to what?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about. Do you understand what a range comparison is and how mysql uses composite indexes?

Comment: @zerkms Exactly my question - what is your source for that information?